# Chrome runtime send multiple message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I have some problem with "onMessage" in my Chrome extension.
So I have plugin, there are 2 button, when I press on **buton1** I send a message in background.js and there I've call the function **"displayManagementTab()"**, in this function I'm loading all data from ***chrome.storage.local*** in table, and I have there about 100 product with a lot of data, and to load it from chrome.storage.local it takes about 7+ seconds.
When it's loading and I'm tried to click **buton2** in plugin to open Settings panel, it's do nothing, until all data from local storage will be loaded, and when loading from chrome.storage.loca has finished buton2 will send a "message" and run function **"displaySettingsTab()"**.

---

Here's code when I addListener to onMessage:

---

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("got message: " + request.command);
        if (request.command == "ok") {
            displayManagementTab();
        }

        if (request.command == "management") {
            displayManagementTab();
        }

        if (request.command == "settings") {
            displaySettingsTab();
        }

        if (request.command == "loadtab") {
            runAmazonInNewTab(request.url);
        }
    });
```

How can I ***request.command == "settings"*** without waiting for *management request* has finished?

Comment: It sounds like `displayManagementTab()` is blocking. Maybe it can be re-written in an asynchronous way, but it's hard to tell unless you show the code for that function.

Comment: More code please, and why not just display settings tab and defer the data loading?

Comment: You might look into using a service worker for the slow code. This would leave the background script free to handle additional messages.

Comment: @abraham can you tell me please how I can handle additional messages?

Comment: @jason you're issue is not handling multiple messages. It will do that just fine. You need to make it so you don't have long running requests and service works should let you put the work in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Using a setTimeout should fix this:

```
if (request.command == "management") {
  setTimeout(displayManagementTab, 0);
}
```